# ORA-02055: distributed update operation failed; rollback required, while using Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Getting this error when executing the below code.

```
DECLARE
  l_output VARCHAR2(200);
  schema_2 varchar2(100) := '';
  count_2 number :=0;
BEGIN

  EXECUTE immediate 'UPDATE T_Reports_Table@ORAT_LINK SET schema_2 = :schema_2, count_2    = :count_2' INTO l_output
  using schema_2,count_2;
  commit;
END;
/
```

However, when I just run the update. Everything goes fine. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps if you show actual code you tried to execute, not fabricated one. Code you posted is invalid and can't return error you mentioned because of the `INTO` clause:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_output varchar2(200);
  3    schema_2 varchar2(100) := '';
  4    count_2 number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'update t_reports_table set schema_2 = :schema_2, count_2 = :count_2'
  7      into l_output                        --> this is wrong
  8      using schema_2, count_2;
  9  end;
 10  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at line 6


SQL> declare
  2    l_output varchar2(200);
  3    schema_2 varchar2(100) := '';
  4    count_2 number := 0;
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'update t_reports_table set schema_2 = :schema_2, count_2 = :count_2'
  7      -- into l_output                   --> without it, procedure is executed
  8      using schema_2, count_2;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So far, the only answer I can offer is: `rollback`.